# React Native: EventEmitter.removeListener('appStateDidChange', ...) - How to debug this?

Tags: react-native

I am kinda new to React Native. I get this warning which is really annoying and spamming the console every other second or so.

```
EventEmitter.removeListener('appStateDidChange', ...): Method has been deprecated. Please instead use `remove()` on the subscription returned by `EventEmitter.addListener`.
```

How do I debug this? The call stack says MeasurementProvider, but there is no `removeListener` anywhere in our code. Does this warning come from a third-party module?

[image]

Comment: Have the same error while setting a state to empty string? any news?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I only get this warning in 1 redux slice out of many which use the exact same code structure for deleting state items... Everything works as it should besides that warning popping up so I simply removed the warning using the code below in App.js

```
import {LogBox} from "react-native";

LogBox.ignoreLogs([
  "EventEmitter.removeListener('appStateDidChange', ...)"
])
```

It's no long-term solution but it'll only show the warning in your dev console this way :)